# how to pass values from jsf-jsp 

Tags: jsf

How can I pass user entered values from/to JSP where I have used JSF as framework? Here is my code:

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{Ack.list}" var="ack" >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText style=""value=" Number" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText style="" value="#{ack.number}" ></h:outputText>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Acknowledgement"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="" > </h:inputText>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value=""/>
        <h:commandButton action="" value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I want to enter some value in the textfield provided for "acknowledgement" and click on submit button. How can I send the user entered "acknowledgment" on button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add a property `acknowledgement` to the class `Ack` (at least, the class which represents each item of the datatable, as declared in `var` attribute of the table).

```
public class Ack {
    private String acknowledgement;

    // Add/generate getter and setter.
}
```

Then bind the input field to that.

```
<h:inputText value="#{ack.acknowledgement}" />
```

Ensure that the table is already placed inside a `<h:form>` and I'd also move the command button outside the table, one button is enough. Bind its `action` to a backing bean method.

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable ...>
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton action="#{Ack.submit}" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

Finally define the method in the bean. At that point, JSF has already set the submitted values. You just have to save them in the DB or something.

```
public String submit() { 
    ackDAO.save(list);
    return "outcome";
}
```